# "Trait not found error" related to the order of definition and content of the trait

Tags: php, traits

I've a PHP file defined in this way.

```
<?php

class A
{
    use T1;
}

trait T1
{
}
```

Everything works as expected until I modify the trait `T1` in this way:

```
<?php

class A
{
    use T1;
}

trait T1
{
    use T2; // Commenting this line the error goes away too.
}

trait T2
{
}
```

Executing `php trait.php` I receive the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'T1' not found in a.php on line 7

Fatal error: Trait 'T1' not found in a.php on line 7
```

- Commenting `use T2;` the error goes away.
- Moving the class `A` after the trait `T2` the error goes away.

**Why `use T2;` triggers this error?**

**Why the order of definition of traits is important?**

---

#### Update 1:

I thought it was a problem related to requiring an external file but the problem seams to be related to the order of definition of the traits. So I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation doesn't say directly (or I could not find it), but I believe a trait must be defined before it can be referenced *by another trait*.  The same is true of objects and their classes.  This is not valid:

```
  $foo = new Foo();

  class Foo extends Bar
  {
  }

  class Bar
  {
  }
```

Because 'Foo' has not been declared before it is used.  This **is** valid however:

```
  class Foo extends Bar
  {
  }

  $foo = new Foo();

  class Bar
  {
  }
```

Even though it doesn't seem like it should be at a glance.

Strangely enough, this is also valid:

```
  class Foo extends Bar
  {
  }

  $foo = new Foo();
  $bar = new Bar();

  class Bar
  {
  }
```

Since the declaration of `Foo` has caused PHP to search the file for `Bar` prior to the instantiation of `Bar` as `$bar`.

Of course, best practices are to only define a single class or trait per file, use a class Autoloader (which works for Traits too), and not put runnable code outside the class or trait definition within those files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
About your statement "I believe a trait must be defined before it can be referenced" my example shows that a trait can be referenced before being defined. The problem arises only when the trait is modified to uses another trait.
In my real case, I don't have runnable code outside the classes/traits definition, but I need to defined multiple classes/traits in the same file. Fortunately I can rearrange the order of definition to workaround the problem.

Comment: I meant to say it (apparently) must be defined before it can be referenced *by another trait*.  I really don't know why PHP makes the distinction, and maybe someone else will come along with a better answer, but my explanation was too long to fit nicely in a comment.

Comment: I updated the answer with that caveat, and clarified it a bit more in other spots.